# Reversing a list of list with string characters

Tags: python, list

I have a problem where I am given a list of lists having strings.
I have to reverse not only the strings but also output a list of lists in reverse way

Example :

```
input_list = [["CAT", "BAT", "SAT"], ["MAN","CHAN", "LAN"], ["CAL", "NJ","NYC"]]
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
[["CYN", "JN", "LAC"], ["NAL", "NAHC", "NAM"], ["TAS", "TAB", "TAC"]]
```

Code I am trying :

```
doc_file = [["CAT", "BAT", "SAT"],
            ["MAN","CHAN", "LAN"],
            ["CAL", "NJ","NYC"]]
temp_list = []
temp_list2 = []
#print("reversing First Line:")
rev_main_list = list(reversed(doc_file))
#print(rev_main_list)
for i in range(len(rev_main_list)):
     for j in range(len(rev_main_list[i])):
        # print("value of i:", i)
        # print("value of j:", j)
        temp_list.append((rev_main_list[i][j][::-1]))
    #print("outer loop i:", i)
    temp_list2.append(temp_list[i])
    rev_main_list =temp_list2
    print(rev_main_list)
```

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse_it(a):
    if isinstance(a,(list,tuple)):
       return [reverse_it(x) for x in a[::-1]]
    return a[::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks, Must be a good fix but need to observe more what is being done here.

Answer (score 0):

```
for small_list in big_list:
    for x in small_list:
        x = x[::-1]
    small_list.reverse()
big_list.reverse()
```

Bit of a clunky fix, but it should work for you.

Comment: I thought in same line. But my solution does not look elegant :

Comment: doc_file = [["CAT", "BAT", "SAT"],
  ["MAN","CHAN", "LAN"],
   ["CAL", "NJ","NYC"]]
   inner_rev = []
print("original_input :") print(doc_file)
                       print("####")
                       rev_main_list = list(reversed(doc_file))
                       further_reverse = [ list(reversed(sub_list)) for sub_list in           rev_main_list]
                       for i in further_reverse :
                       inner_rev.append([sub_list_2[::-1] for sub_list_2 in i])
                       print("final output:")
                       print (inner_rev)

Comment: Not working . Output I get is : [['NYC', 'NJ', 'CAL'], ['LAN', 'CHAN', 'MAN'], ['SAT', 'BAT', 'CAT']]